# JUnit tests works fine into Eclipse but don't work with "build gradle" command. Its failing with dependency error

Tags: java, gradle, junit

Java Version: **1.8**
Gradle Version **5.6.4**
JUNIT: **junit-jupiter:5.7.0**
SO: **Linux**

I have this project estructure:

Project
1.Domain
2.Core
3.Batch

This project have 4 files "build.gradle", 1 for each context and the main, example:

Main Build.Gradle (root folder):

```
configurations {
    compileClasspath
}

subprojects {
    group = 'project'
    version = 'project-1.0.0'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url fintecc_aws_url
            credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                accessKey fintecc_aws_userkey
                secretKey fintecc_aws_secretkey
            }
        }
    }
    
    jar {
        version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
        from ("${projectDir}/src/main/java") {
            include("**/*.json")
            include("**/*.html")
        }
    }

    ext {
        fffCommonsVersion = "2.0.11-BETA15"
        orgProjectLombok = "1.16.8"
        slf4jLogVersion = "1.7.5"
        commonsIoCommonsIo = 2.6
        //
        //
        testJunitVersion = "5.3.1"
        testMockitoVersion = "2.23.4"
    }

    dependencies {
        //
        // Lombok
        compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:${orgProjectLombok}")
        testCompileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:${orgProjectLombok}")
        annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:${orgProjectLombok}")
        testAnnotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:${orgProjectLombok}")     
        //
        // Junit/Tests
        testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0")
        testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4")
        //
        // Commons and Log
        compile("fff.commons:serverless:${fffCommonsVersion}")
        implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:${slf4jLogVersion}")
        compile("commons-io:commons-io:${commonsIoCommonsIo}")
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

Each subproject build.gradle (batch/ folder):

```
project(':batch') {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    
        eclipse {
                project {
                        name = 'ttt_project_batch'
                }
        }
    
        dependencies {
            compile project(':core'),
            "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:1.11.586",
            "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.250",
            "com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.0.0",
            "mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.2"
        }
        
        jar {
            baseName = 'batch'
            version = '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
                
            from {
                configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
            }
        
            from ("${projectDir}/src/main/java") {
                include("**/*.json")
                include("**/*.xml")
            }
        
            into('lib') {
                from configurations.compile
            }
        
            manifest {
                def manifestFile = "${projectDir}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"
                if (new File(manifestFile).exists()) {
                    from File(manifestFile)
                }
                else {
                    manifest.attributes(
                        'Main-Class': 'config.BatchConfig',
                        "Project":project.name,
                        "Specification-Vendor":"XXXXX",
                        "Created-By":org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My settings.gradle file:

```
include 'domain', 'core', 'batch'
```

All right, the project compiles correctly. When I added the JUNIT tests, I was able to run perfectly inside the eclipse just fine... Into **batch/src/test/java/**

But when I run command "build gradle" into terminal to generate JAR file, JUNIT's dependency is not being recognized, like this:

```
Execution failed for task ':batch:compileTestJava'.

error: package org.junit does not exist
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
```

Has anyone ever experienced this? I believe the cause is the project being modularized

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem
I am using JUNIT 5 but my dependencies were JUNIT 4-

In my eclipse works because I had imported JUNIT 4 manually in the past... I couldn't remember

I just replace:

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals
to
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals